# What's the easiest way to animate a line?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, animation, core-animation

I am creating an app that involves animating lines within a workspace over time. My current approach for this is to use code like this in `drawRect`:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, black);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, finalPoint.x, finalPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

...and then just setting a timer to run every 0.05 seconds to update `finalPoint` and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

I'm finding this approach (when there's 5ish lines moving at once) slows down the app terribly, and even with such a high refresh frequency, still appears jerky.

There must be some better way to perform this very simple line drawing in an animated line - i.e. saying that I want a line to start at x1, y1 and stretching to x2, y2 over a given length of time. What are my options for this? I need to make this perform faster and would love to get rid of this clunky timer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use CAShapeLayers, and a combination of CATransactions and CABasicAnimation.

You can add a given path to a shapeLayer and let it do the rendering.

A CAShapeLayer object has two properties called `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, which defines where along the path the end of the line should render. The defaults are 0.0 for `strokeStart`, and 1.0 for `strokeEnd`.

If you set up your path so that `strokeEnd` initially starts at 0.0, you will see no line.

You can then animate, from 0.0 to 1.0, the `strokeEnd` property and you will see the line lengthen.

To change CAShapeLayer's implicit 0.25s default animation timing, you can add a function to the class, like so:

```
-(void)animateStrokeEnd:(CGFloat)_strokeEnd {
    [CATransaction begin];
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
    animation.duration = 2.0f; //or however long you want it to happen
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.strokeEnd]; // from the current strokeEnd value
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_strokeEnd]; //to the end of the path
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ self.strokeEnd = _strokeEnd }];
    [self addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateStrokeEnd"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

You can pass any value from 0.0f to 1.0f as the value of `_strokeEnd`.

The `setCompletionBlock:` ensures that the value you are passing is explicitly set after the animation completes.